# C# RDLC report viewer - Displaying multiple Images from Database - not working

Tags: c#, image, rdlc

I need to build a report viewer that has a contents of multiple data, including Images (mediumBlob) data field from MySQL database (not image path).
I created a Dataset that contains multiple tables of data then feed them to the report viewer.
The image field is set to System.Byte[] of course.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2aNV.png)
All the data is viewing fine but only the images got error like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X11Pd.png)

My code:

```
    private void finMOM_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        string year = today.Year.ToString();
        string month = today.Month.ToString();
        string day = today.Day.ToString();
        tbxSubject.Text = $"[{ProjectCode}] MOM{year}{month}{day}";

        rpvMOM.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        DataTable mom = MOMDAO.Instance.LoadMOMByID(MomID);
        DataTable attendee = AttendeeDAO.Instance.LoadAttendee(MomID);
        DataTable matter = MatterDAO.Instance.LoadMatter(MomID);
        ReportDataSource momds = new ReportDataSource("MOM", mom);
        ReportDataSource attendeeds = new ReportDataSource("Attendee", attendee);
        ReportDataSource matterds = new ReportDataSource("Matter", matter);
        rpvMOM.LocalReport.ReportPath = "inMOM.rdlc";
        rpvMOM.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(momds);
        rpvMOM.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(attendeeds);
        rpvMOM.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(matterds);
        rpvMOM.RefreshReport();
    }
```

Please help me solve this somehow.
Thank you in advance.

It should be like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5zPO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution, actually quite simple:

1. Add image inside a table from toolbox:
   [Add image inside the data field of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YCvi.png)
2. Change Image properties to fit your need:
   [Properties image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3q2t.png)
3. Results:
   [Awsome!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOdLh.png)